# Как правильно обойтись с высотой элементов

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Я только начинаю, поэтому сильно не пинайте.

Делаю шапку, http://prntscr.com/n338xc  в ней есть 4 блока. Высота формируется по высоте контента. У каждого блока есть бордер справа. У первого и второго блока с бордером все хорошо, а у 3 не хватает высоты, чтобы этот бордер коснулся нижней границы шапки. Это происходит из-за того что высота дочерних элементов первого и второго блока одинаковы, а высота третьего блока уже меньше.

Как правильно в данном случае верстать? Все остальные блоки подгонять под высоту первого блока с помощью padding?

Comment: код покажите свой

Comment: Flex-box вам в помощь. Хотя в вашем случае проще просто явно указать высоту блоков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кода нет, поэтому приведу пример своего.

```css
.header__container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: pink;
}

.header__wrapper {
  padding: 16px;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
}

.header__wrapper:first-child .header__wrapper-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header__container">
      <div class="header__wrapper">
        <div class="header__wrapper-item">
          <span>1</span>
          <span>2</span>
          <span>3</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header__wrapper">
        <div class="header__wrapper-item">
          <span>1</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header__wrapper">
        <div class="header__wrapper-item">
          <span>1</span>
          <span>2</span>
          <span>3</span>
          <span>4</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header__wrapper">
        <div class="header__wrapper-item">
          <span>1</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```